# How to convert MemoryStream to StreamContent[] in C# in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to convert from `MemoryStream` to `StreamContent` list.

I use this to convert the list to MemoryStream (ms):

```
ms.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(listStreamContent));
```

And I try to use this to receive the streamContent:

```
ms.Position = 0;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    string line;

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        listStreamContentBack.Add(line);
    }
}
```

I know that this code doesn't work. Does someone know how I could do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: The `StreamContent` constructor accepts a base `Stream`, why won't that work for you?   `var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);`

Comment: Kind of doesn't make sense: `StreamContent` is for a *whole* stream, not just a line